# "The selection cannot be run on any server"

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I've been working on a dynamic web project in Eclipse. I am getting this error.

> "The selection cannot be run on any server".

Earlier it was working fine but now I'm getting this error. I removed the server and added it again.

`Project`->`Right Click`-> `Properties`->`Server` No server is showing here and two options are there Restore Default and Apply. I am not able to add server here.

Please tell me want is the problem with this.

POM.XML

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>try</groupId>
<artifactId>try</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>try Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<!-- Dependencies -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId> 
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.132</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>try</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing Dynamic Web Project into Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972447/importing-dynamic-web-project-into-eclipse)

Comment: I did it but still not working

Comment: This may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601193/eclipse-maven-spring-server-error-when-i-try-to-run-as-server-tomcat-7

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know that is a bit late, but maybe helps someone in the future. 
Go to Project Facets and make sure you have select the properly java version(in my case should be 1.7 for weblogic 12.1.3) and the version for Dynamic Web Module(in my case should be 3.0, not bigger). 
To make sure that your app will run, here in project facets, in Runtimes tab, it will be displayed your server.
This will work for sure ;)

Comment: in my case should be 3.0, not bigger -> that was the deal for me. Downgraded from 4.0 to 3.0 and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Right-click on project (alt + enter) > properties > project facts.

Make sure that you have selected the checkbox of **Dynamic web module (3.0)** and select the proper **java version (1.8)**.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the server might not be selected in project. Go to properties -> Server
Select the server you want to run this project on.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:   Right click on your project> build path> configure build path>project facets> change the version of java.(current version, which is installed in your computer)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I:

1. Right click project in Project Explorer
2. Select Run As -> Run on Server
3. Click Finish without selecting a server

I was being lazy and thinking that since there is only one server, it would automatically pick that one, but apparently not. It seems odd that the wizard would let me do that and give such a nonsensical error message.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error mentioned in the heading, that the selection could not be run on any server. This was because when we start our JSP application on the server we have to add our resources.

1. Right click on the project
2. Run application on the server
3. Select available server and click Next
4. Add resources and click Finish

[image: Image showing results]

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the `html` file to run is under `webapp\WEB-INF`, after fix move to `webapp`, it run successfully show the html in browser.

Besides, in Run On Server view as below, if you directly click `Finish`, then get error, click the `Tomcat v10.1 Server at localhost` first and `Finish`, then works.

[image: Run On Server]